# Form Field - Enter Part of URL and go to Full URL Destination

Tags: forms, url, field

How to create a form field where the user enters in part of a URL and then clicks to visit that full URL?

Example. [type our company name here].website.com (Submit Button) -> goes to companyname.website.com

I need the full code snippet for this one, from  to  please. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you done so far? Nobody on SO writes whole code for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I could give you some advice I would suggest taking a crack at answering the problem yourself first and you will have a better chance of receiving positive responses.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML/PHP you can do :

HTML Form :

```
<form method="post" action="target.php">
<input type="text" name="beforeUrl" />.website.com
<input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
header('Location: http://'.$_POST['beforeUrl'].'.website.com');
?>
```

PS : It's basic code but you do protect your POST var.